# Ubuntu Login failure

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I'm having a problem with a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 10.04. I am able to enter a user name, but after hitting enter, the keyboard is locked out and I can't enter anything. This issue is also present in fresh installs of Server 9.10 and Servr 10.10. It is also present in the desktop editions 9.04, 10, and 10.10 when attempting to use either the gnome terminal or console. This problem has manifested itself on 2 of my systems now and no apparent solution. I've run checkdisk from the Cd menu which in each case has reported that the disks match the md5 sums, so it doesn't appear to be a bad ISO. 1 system ie early P4 using the I 850 chipset, and I'd read somewhere that the I850 chipset had a known compatability issue with Ubuntu, although I've never been able to find that thread again. The other is a LGA 775 P4 using a I925 chipset. Browising the list of compatable hardware does not indicate that I should be having a problem with either. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix my problem?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that entering a password on the terminal does NOT echo anything (No **** or other placeholder characters.)

It may appear that the keyboard is locked or not responding but it isn't. Simply enter your password and press Enter. This is a security measure (I guess) so that people cannot see how long your password is by counting the "*" characters

Answer (score 0):

To login use the on-screen keyboard (Man with the circle around it) (Need a GUI obviously), once inside run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to configure your keyboard and see if that fixes the problem.